# Laravel - please explain Naming Controller Routes 'uses', 'as'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm sure this is very simple, but I do not understand. Please explain this, from the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers):

> Naming Controller Routes Like Closure routes, you may specify names on
>   controller routes:

`Route::get('foo', ['uses' => 'FooController@method', 'as' => 'name']);`

I am unclear as to the purpose of 'uses', 'as', and 'name', and how to use them.

---

**Update:**

So I have named a route closure as `'bar'` but I get a `NotFoundHttpException` when trying to call `/bar` or `/qux` in the URL

```
Route::get('foo', ['as' => 'bar', function() {
    dd('foo');
}]);

Route::get('qux', function() {
    action('bar');
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`uses` specifies which class you're calling when the route hits, and which method on that class. So for Laravel 5.1, with your example, that would by default be the method `method()` on the class `app/Http/Controllers/FooController.php`

`as` means you give the route a name, so that it's easier to link to it later. Let's say you have ten views and you link to the same route from all of them. If you change the format of the link, you'll have to track each one individually and change them as well. But if you have given your route a name, you don't have to change anything, because they'll just look the route up by that name.

Putting it together, let's say you have a webshop and you want a route for your customers page, and that you want to link to it from your views. It might look something like this:

```
Route::get('customers', [
    'uses' => 'ShopController@customers',
    'as' => 'customers'
]);
```

Comment: Gave it a shot but not working - perhaps making an error or missing the point completely. Please see updated question

Comment: Your updated problem is that the address to your route is `/foo`, and it has been given an internal name of `bar`, but you're trying to access it at `/bar`. That doesn't work. The name and the link are two different things. Might I suggest follow a tutorial? You're on the right track but these are kinda basic issues and you may want to review them from scratch.

Comment: I think I fixed it, by changing `action('bar')` to `redirect(route('bar'))`

Answer (score 0):

The `uses` property defines the controller and method your route will call where the first part `FooController` is the name of the controller and after the `@` is the name of the method in `FooController`. The method and its controller must exist.

The `as` property specifies the name of the route and allows you to conveniently call the route by its name e.g `Redirect::route('routeName');` and similarly get the routes address by `URL::route('routeName')` which is handy in views (Note: this is Laravel 4.2 syntax)

In your edit you are experiencing an issue because you are attempting to use the routes name as the address of the route. The address is the first property in the route and `foo` in your example. If you want to visit the route through the address bar you will need to use the routes complete address (take into consideration group prefixes as well).